# Call Java classes based on the list content

Tags: java

I want to call Java Classes based on Java list items:

```
List<RiskFilters> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new RiskFilters(21, "TicketSize"));
list.add(new RiskFilters(4, "TestSize"));
list.add(new RiskFilters(5, "ModuleSize"));
list.add(new RiskFilters(3, "ModuleDate"));
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(RiskFilters::getPosition));
```

I have `Filters` Objects which I would like to call based on the Java list order.

```
// Call the filters like this

TicketSizeFilter())
ModuleNameFilter();
ModuleDateFilter();
SystemNameFilter();
```

The question is how to design the Java call to call the Java classes based on the sorted items from the list?

Comment: Iterate over your list and check the second string. With if statements or a switch

Comment: yes with `switch` I can implement it but what if I have a random numbers for order?

Comment: Order doesn't matter since you just compare the strings

Comment: hm... if I first sort the list and then call them one by one based on the position into the list maybe it will work?

Comment: Is there some more elegant way?

Comment: Just sort the list. The loop over the sorted list. So the first item will be the first item in your sorted list. Like the answer below

Comment: just in case is there other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to play a bit with reflection:

```
List<RiskFilters> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new RiskFilters(21, "TicketSize"));
        list.add(new RiskFilters(4, "TestSize"));
        list.add(new RiskFilters(5, "ModuleSize"));
        list.add(new RiskFilters(3, "ModuleDate"));

        // easier way to sort 
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(RiskFilters::getPosition));

        for (RiskFilters f : list)
        {
            try {
                Method m = RiskFilters.class.getDeclaredMethod(f.getFilter() + "Filter");
                m.invoke(f);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

if the method being called receives, for example, a String parameter, you could do like this:

```
Method m = RiskFilters.class.getDeclaredMethod(f.getFilter() + "Filter", String.class);
                m.invoke(f, "hello hello");
```

Comment: Can you show me how to pass arguments to the Java Classes?

Comment: you mean to the constructor of a class or to pass to a method?

Comment: to a method into the class

Comment: @PeterPenzov - I've updated my post with an example passing a String as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers provided so far, for better/readable code, you could also maintain an Enum having all the variables corresponding to "TicketSize", "TextSize","ModuleSize","ModuleDate" etc.. and use that enum when comparing.

You can define the enum as :

```
public enum FilterName {

TicketSize("TicketSizeFilter"), TextSize("TextSizeFilter"), ModuleSize("ModuleSizeFilter"),
ModuleDate("ModuleDateFilter");
private String action;

public String getAction() {
    return this.action;
}

FilterName(String action) {
    this.action = action;
}
}
```

And the calling code can be like this :

```
for (RiskFilters f : list)
 {
     try {
         Method m = RiskFilters.class.getDeclaredMethod(FilterName.valueOf(f.getType()).getAction() + "Filter");
         m.invoke(f, obj1, obj2, "input"); // can add any number of arguments and any type based on the signature of method being invoked
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // do something
     }
 }
```

You can pass argument while invoking methods through reflection.
`m.invoke(f, arg1,arg2,arg3)

method signature being -- java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object...)`

Comment: just curious what is the performance of this solution is it faster than switch case if I have 50 cases?

Comment: Switch cases are usually advised to keep short not more that 5 cases. If you are keeping more cases that that then it is not considered a good coding practice. Also, cost of comparing enum is the same as comparing strings (may be faster) . And most of all, its gets rid of the multiple if -else or switch cases. It makes the code much more maintainable & readable.

Comment: Well in my case I have around 18 cases. Alternatives except reflection?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `switch-case`:

```
for (RiskFilters r: list) {
 String s = r.getString();
 switch(s) {
  case "TicketSize":
    TicketSizeFilter();
    break;
  case "TestSize":
    ModuleNameFilter();
    break;
  case "ModuleSize":
    ModuleDateFilter();
    break;
  case "ModuleDate":
    SystemNameFilter();
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes but how to call them using the order from the Java List?

Comment: @PeterPenzov since I'm using `for` on the list's items, the functions will be called by the corresponding order of the items.